# Is certain function on sets transitive?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, relations

Let $U$ be a set.

Suppose $f:\mathscr{P}U\to\mathscr{P}U$ is a function satisfying $f(\varnothing)=\varnothing$ and $f(A\cup B)=f(A)\cup f(B)$.

I denote $\left(\bigsqcup_{f\in S}f\right)(X) = \bigcup_{f\in S}f(X)$.

**Conjecture** $(1\sqcup f\sqcup f^2\sqcup\dots)\circ(1\sqcup f\sqcup f^2\sqcup\dots) = 1\sqcup f\sqcup f^2\sqcup\dots$

(here $1$ is the identity relation on $U$ and $\circ$ is composition of functions with $f^n = f\circ\dots\circ f$ ($n$ times)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Counterexample (please check for errors):

Consider $f:\mathscr{P}\mathbb{R}\to\mathscr{P}\mathbb{R}$ defined by the formula

$$ f (E) = \operatorname{cl} \bigcup \left\{ \left[ \frac{- 1 - |
   a |}{2} ; \frac{1 + | a |}{2} \right] \mid a \in E
   \right\} $$

(here $\operatorname{cl}$ is the usual topological closure for real numbers).

Take $X = \left[ - \frac{1}{2} ; \frac{1}{2} \right]$. $f^n
(X) = \left[ - 1 + \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} ; 1 - \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} \right]$.

We have $(1 \sqcup f \sqcup f^2 \sqcup \ldots ) (X) =] - 1 ; 1 [$;

$(1 \sqcup f \sqcup f^2 \sqcup \ldots )((1 \sqcup f
\sqcup f^2 \sqcup \ldots) (X)) = [- 1 ; 1]$.

Thus follows $(1 \sqcup f \sqcup f^2 \sqcup \ldots) \circ (1 \sqcup f \sqcup f^2 \sqcup
\ldots) \neq 1 \sqcup f \sqcup f^2 \sqcup ...$